# Assignment of struct char array to char array in C is giving an "incompatible types in assignment" error

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I am trying to assign a char array of size 88 to a structure's char array of size 88 property, but when I compile the program, I get:

> error: incompatible types in assignment

Here is where I define my struct:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 9
/* Bounded Buffer item structure */
typedef struct item {
   int  id;       /* String index value */
   char str[88];  /* String value */
}item;
```

I declare the item as a global variable:

```
item buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
int bufferFill;
```

I am setting the property in another file, so I declare them in the other file as well using extern:

```
extern item buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
extern int bufferFill;
```

Inside of a function in the same file that I redeclared them as external global variables, I declare a new char array:

```
char outputString[88];
```

I originally had it as:

```
char * outputString;
```

That gave the same error that I am still getting, so I tried changing it so that the array was declared with the same size as the one in the struct.

After I fill outputStrings with data, I try to set the buffer's str array to outputStrings.

```
buffer[bufferFill].str = outputString;
```

This gives the error:

> incompatible types in assignment during compile time.

I have no idea what is wrong. I have even done things similar to this before with no problems, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have set the other property of the item struct with no problem like this:

```
buffer[bufferFill].id = num;  // This gives no error
```

In setting the `str` property I have also tried:

```
buffer[bufferFill].str = (char *)outputString;
```

and

```
buffer[bufferFill].str = &outputString;
```

I didn't expect those to work, but I tried them anyway. They of course did not work.

I am completely lost as to what could be causing this when as far as I can tell, they are the same type.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy character strings, use:-

```
strncpy(buffer[bufferFill].str,outputString,88); //88 is the size of char str[88] array.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. I do want to note for anyone looking at this for help with their own issues that it should be strncpy(buffer[bufferFill].str,outputString,88); because the size of both arrays is 88, BUFFERSIZE = 9.

Comment: @Jason247: You are correct. It should be 88 (i.e. the size of char str[] array), not BUFFERSIZE. Would edit the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use strcpy() or strncpy() for copying strings (which are char arrays).